# .htaccess redirect doens't work correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using a .htaccess to get all documents from an old site to the new one. The old site doesn't support PHP or mod_rewrite. I tried the following code:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.new.com/archive/
```

I requested " http://www.new.com/archive/index.html"
Which resulted into

```
http://www.new.com/archive/old.com/olddir/&&&/&&&/users/4/web/00/00/24/04/44/&&&/1/&&&/0/&&&/&&&/&&&/users/4/web/00/00/24/04/44/&&&/1/&&&/0/&&&/index.html
```

Is this possible to solve?

Comment: looks like that URL is being rewritten somewhere else, that redirect looks fine... I think you need to post more code to get a reliable answer.

Comment: The problem is, there is no more code. (as far as I can access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can probable not be solved with .htaccess. Instead I used javascript. It's not good for SEO, but there seems to be no other way.